# ¿Como crear un link de descarga que apunte al servidor de mi API y no a localhost?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estoy teniendo un ligero problema con la descarga de archivos de una API, probando directamente desde ella lo hace correctamente, pero cuando lo hago desde local no.

Obviamente, si la API es externa el link de descarga tiene que ser `blob:link de la API/...`.

La cuestión sería, ¿Cómo hacer para apuntar a ese link partiendo del siguiente código?

Partiendo de que tengo respuesta de la API, lo que intento hacer es lo siguiente:

```javascript
const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data], {type:'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' }));

const link = document.createElement('a');

link.href = url;

link.setAttribute('download', `ListadoFiltradoInmuebles-${Date.now()}`);

document.body.appendChild(link);
link.click();
```

Lo que quiero conseguir, como he dicho antes, es que el URL no sea `blob:http://localhost/...` si no `blob:https://servidor/...`

¿Alguna idea al respecto?